# Send email to Outlook using content generated in Java

Tags: java, html, email, outlook

I have a Java program that needs to be able to send the subject,body and recipient of an email to Outlook. The email is HTML formatted. I have searched around, but the only things I can find are on how to send the email USING Java. This is not what I need to do. I need to generate the mail, then give it to Outlook to send from there.

The problem is that I have no idea on how to go about this. I can't think of any way to send the information over to Outlook except the `MAILTO:` protocol, which cannot transport HTML data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question for you: does the Java program live on a website? If so, what's the language of that website (PHP, ASP, ColdFusion, etc.)?

Comment: No, it's a local program.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an EML (MIME) file and provide a link to that file instead of a mailto link. Outlook will open and display the EML file.